# Eclipse stops console from clearing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, console

I'm having problems with Eclipse automatically clearing the console after doing Maven builds. This doesn't seem to happen all the time, but because of this I can't see the results.
Does anybody know how to change this behavior?

Comment: Also note that the button to the left of minimise will list several different consoles.

Comment: Check this question where I am looking for a way to prevent the auto close of console logs of terminated lauches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411795/how-to-prevent-eclipse-from-auto-closing-terminated-lauches-console-log

Answer (score 23):

Prevent the Eclipse console from clearing as follows:

1. Select **Window » Preferences** to show the **Preferences** dialog
2. Expand **Run/debug**
3. Select **Console**
4. Uncheck **Limit Console output**
5. Click **OK** to accept the new preferences and close the dialog

[image]

Comment: This helps, but it does not completely eliminate all the cases where a console may clear (for example I believe when resources are scarce, eclipse will clear it anyway).  Redirecting is likely the better catch-all approach.

Comment: @demongolem the problem is the redirection priority, I would prefer MUCH more to redirect the useless ant auto build successful log messages than my precious application error log! :) any idea/news on this?

Answer (score 10):

There are different types of consoles. You have a `Console` which contains the output of your Java programs, there is also a `Maven console` which contains the output of the Maven plug-in.

[image]

Besides there are other console types like an SVN console...

To keep the console output you could redirect the output of your applications to a file. You can do this in the `Run Configurations` dialog on the `Common` tab.

Comment: redirect to a file ? Why don't they just keep it in the editor, or could it be that my maven console disappears after the job is finished.

Comment: No it will stay there, you can switch between them. I mentioned the possibility of redirecting as additional information not as a suggestion.

Comment: @Kai I am searching for the inverse: I wonder if it is possible to redirect the Ant Build execution procedure/output to any other place, other than my application console output. There must have a way or I will disable ant auto build too as he did :)

Comment: @AquariusPower if you can't find a similar question here you should start a new one.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411795/how-to-prevent-eclipse-from-auto-closing-terminated-lauches-console-log?noredirect=1#comment60440673_36411795)

Answer (score -3):

I found the solution myself, I had the ant-builder enabled in a part of my program, and this causes the consoles to disappear.

Right click project => properties => builders => disable the ant builder

Comment: hehehe, have you found a way to let ant builder remain enabled and still do not overwrite the console? :), I am almost doing that too, just lost my error log.. again...