# How to prevent Eclipse from auto closing TERMINATED lauches console log?

Tags: eclipse, logging

**After** an application launch/execution **TERMINATES** (so it is not running anymore), it's console log remains there for review, until we start another execution.

When a new execution happens (even from ant auto build), all terminated launches console log are automatically closed.

So, how can we avoid the console log auto-closing of **TERMINATED** launches/executions?

For me at least, this is important so we can keep ant auto build enabled. Because **ANT AUTO BUILD** will **REPLACE TERMINATED** execution logs.

EDIT: I tried the answers for the [question marked as duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different), but they did not work. The ended lauches log continued being replaced. Therefore this is not a duplicate. But I found the right answer, and asked the commenter @deinocheirus to answer here, so I can mark this as solved.

Comment: Hey. I can't add an answer to this question, probably because it's been tagged as duplicate.

Comment: @deinocheirus yes, we will have to wait for total of 5 reopen votes until you can do that :(

Comment: @deinocheirus good news dude! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261151/in-eclipse-can-i-have-multiple-console-views-at-once-each-showing-a-different is not really duplicate for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching. Uncheck the property '**Remove terminates launches when a new launch is created**'